# MATLAB: How to use cellfun with a struct?

Tags: matlab, struct, cell-array

Imagine a cell array that consists of identical structs (in terms of layout), as the example `cellArray` below. How can I apply `cellfun` to a specific field of these structs?

```
cellArray{1,1}.val1 = 10;
cellArray{1,1}.val2 = 20;
cellArray{1,2}.val1 = 1000;
cellArray{1,2}.val2 = 2000;
```

How to use cellfun in order to add the value 50 to all cells, but only to the field `val2`?

```
out = cellfun(@plus, cellArray?????, {50, 50}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: Do the docs mention this particular case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a custom function `add_val2(x, y)`, which adds `y` to the field `x.val2`, and call `cellfun()` with `@add_val2` instead of `@plus`.

First, create the function `add_val2.m`:

```
function x = add_val2(x, y)
    x.val2 = x.val2 + y;
end
```

Then, calling `cellfun()` is as simple as

```
out = cellfun(@add_val2, cellArray, {50, 50}, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

which results in

```
>> out{1}
ans = 
  struct with fields:
    val1: 10
    val2: 70

>> out{2}
ans = 
  struct with fields:
    val1: 1000
    val2: 2050
```